# Include exclude patterns rsync relative

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm trying to sync a large tree on Linux, but include and exclude certain files/directories. My question is regarding rsync's **--relative** option and how relative paths are handled. Directory structures appear something like:

```
/x/z1/company1/file1
/x/z2/company2/file1
/x/z3/company3/dir1/file3
/x/z4/company1/dir2
/x/z5/company1/dir3/file4
```

I want to transfer directories and files under 'company?' **non-recursively**. This (so far) appears to do what I am after:

```
rsync -a --relative /x/./z? --include '/x/*/*/*' --exclude '/x/*/*/*/*' a@b:/x
```

How could I specify the inc/excl rules as *relative* paths? What would this do?

```
rsync -a --relative /x/./z? --include '*/*/*/*' --exclude '*/*/*/*/*' a@b:/x
```

How will the patterns match? In order words, are the patterns relative to /x or to /x/./z ?

Comment: Please remember to include your operating system in your question. Is this Linux, AIX, UNIX, OSX, BeOS, what?